# Error while installing Elasticsearch 5.6.4 as a Windows service

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

This is ridiculous:

I downloaded the ElasticSearch 5.6.4 zip file from the official website, unzipped it into a folder and then run the command

> ./elasticsearch-service.bat

in both PowerShell and standard Windows console

The output is an error message:

> Syntax Error

[image]

[image]

I haven't change anything, just downloaded and run it out of the box. Adding the `install` and `servicename` parameters doesn't change anything

Comment: That error is coming from the shell script (batch file) that you are running. I suggest asking the author of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just encountered with the similar issue. Although the error message is different. It is something like

```
'x64).exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Try to run .bat without `./` prefix.

Comment: tried. Got a "The term elasticsearch-service.bat is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again"

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Try to run it from standard windows console, not from PowerShell. Is the result still the same?

Comment: same error unfortunately, please check my edit on the question. I've added another snapshot

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Ok, I suppose the only reason of syntax error are your environment variables. `elasticsearch-service.bat` uses quite a lot of them. First of all check JAVA_HOME variable (it should not inlcude double quotes) then pay attention to the others.